# What is the order of code execution in Citrus test cases

Tags: citrus-framework

While developing Citrus test cases (Citrus version 2.7.2 on Linux) I noted that methods seem to be executed in a different order than specified in code. This is an example of a test:

```
@CitrusTest
public void testOrderOfMethods() throws InterruptedException {

    log.info(">> Starting test");

    http()
            .client(wiremockClient)
            .send()
            .get("/__admin/requests")
            .accept("application/json");

    http()
            .client(wiremockClient)
            .receive()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK)
            .messageType(MessageType.JSON);

    log.info(">> Test completed");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    log.info(">> Waited a while");
}
```

The output produced by this code is:

```
14:35:19 14:35:19,133 INFO         citrus.Citrus|
14:35:19 14:35:19,133 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:35:19 14:35:19,145 DEBUG t.TestContextFactory| Created new test context - using global variables: '{}'
14:35:19 14:35:19,145 INFO           junk.JunkIT| >> Starting test
14:35:19 14:35:19,146 INFO           junk.JunkIT| >> Test completed
14:35:21 14:35:21,146 INFO           junk.JunkIT| >> Waited a while
14:35:21 14:35:21,146 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:35:21 14:35:21,146 INFO         citrus.Citrus|     
14:35:21 14:35:21,146 DEBUG        citrus.Citrus| STARTING TEST JunkIT.testOrderOfMethods <esb.junk>
14:35:21 14:35:21,146 INFO         citrus.Citrus| 
14:35:21 14:35:21,146 DEBUG      citrus.TestCase| Initializing test case
```

So, the 3 log lines (Starting test, Test completed, Waited a while) are printed before the Citrus http() calls, even though the test waits 2 seconds before "Waited a while" is printed.

That's what happens if I run my test with Jenkins as a Maven job. If I run my test in a debugger, the order of statements is as suggested by the source code.

My question is: are calls to Citrus somehow executed after other code (on another tread maybe)? If so, how can I enforce the order of code in Citrus test methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use TestRunner instead of TestDesigner in Citrus.

The designer will first collect all test actions, construct the whole test case and execute it at the end of construction.

The runner will execute the actions immediately as they are constructed in the Java DSL method calls.

The different approaches and strategies of designer and runner are also described in more detail in the reference documentation: http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/#writing-test-cases-in-java

Comment: I see, thanks for the reference that explains what is happening. I decided to wrap my code in an action because if you inherit from TestNGCitrusTestRunner, calls to soap() or http() stop working (they need a BuilderSupport parameter and if you add that calls to .client() have to be changed). So wrapping my non-Citrus code seemed easier. Also, I couldn't find a full example of how to use TestNGCitrusTestRunner.